# A random function is not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to generate a random number which will be unique from the numbers stored in the mysql database. I have written the following function to generate. But it is not working.

```
function random(){
    $invoice = rand(0,9999);

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT order_ID FROM premises WHERE order_ID='$invoice'");
    $match = mysql_num_rows($check);

    echo $invoice;
    echo "sdhfji";

    if($match == 0){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders values('$invoice','$id','$name','$key_num')");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO persons values('$invoice','$fname','$lname','$address','$phone','$email'.'$business')") or die(mysql_error());
    }else{
        random();
    }

    echo $invoice;
}
```

It is not entering into the function. Please help me if there is any alternative way.

Comment: What do you mean by its not "entering" into the function? Is the function not being called? In that case, posting the function code is rather useless...

Comment: SQL has nothing to do with PHP random.

Comment: What is this funtion supposed to do? This makes no sense! If it doesnt "entering" the if-statement (I thinkt you mean this but writes function) of $match==0 then $match != 0.

Comment: Did you heard about "AUTO_INCREMENT"?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Unfortunately i can not use auto increment because the order_ID field will be initially empty and will be updated by random number.

Comment: So you want to assign IDs to already inserted posts?

Answer (score 0):

dFirst of, use mysqli since mysql is deprecated as of php 5.5 (to future proof your work).
I dont get what the purpose of this "random function" is, but I guess you simply want to insert a post into the database and insert "link" that post into another table?

```
/* cant figure out what the diffrenece in invoice and id is. Pls provice database-structure to improve this answer */

$query = "INSERT id (id, name, key_num )INTO orders values('$id','$name','$key_num')";

$mysqli->query($query);

//Get id from latest query
$latest_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;

$query = "INSERT INTO persons values('$last_id','$fname','$lname','$address','$phone','$email'.'$business')";

$mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: invoice and order_ID are same here.